# android app works on Genymotion but not in real phone

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I have a problem with an application since 2-3 weeks. The app works fine at emulator but when I want to debugging this in a real phone the app crash, launching this error on Logcat and shows a white screen.

```
D/AccessibilityManager: setStateLocked: wasEnabled = false, mIsEnabled = false, wasTouchExplorationEnabled = false, mIsTouchExplorationEnabled = false, wasHighTextContrastEnabled = false, mIsHighTextContrastEnabled = false
java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked
```

The line that generates error is it, this activity extends from AppCompatActivity and the xml layout use a custom surface view.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Anybody have the same problem? What I should do for solve that?

Comment: Does this happen on all environments (i.e. if you try to deploy it to a different physical device, does it still happen)? If you try to deploy a "blank" app, does it still happen? Did your app ever work on the testing device?

Comment: I test 4.1.1 to 5.1 version of Android in different emulators and in all works fine but I debug in a real phone breaks.

Comment: Yes, but what if you deploy it to a different physical device (or deploy a "blank" app to your current test device)? Also, did you *ever* have your app working on your current device or did it "break" after a change?

Comment: I resolve the problem, the memory that the app used are excesive. In the real phone crashed but in emulator worked, now works in the two systems.

Answer (score 0):

StateLocked means your phone is locked with a passcode. Is it so? If yes then try unlocking your phone, or even temporarily removing the passcode/combination swipe and see if this is resolved.

EDIT: Might be a duplicate:[There's some error when android loading layout,but have no effective on running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792043/theres-some-error-when-android-loading-layout-but-have-no-effective-on-running)

Comment: It's impossible, this phone don't have any passcode.

Comment: That post can't resolve my problem, continues launching this error.